# How to send request to another page and let the second page grab the request and do something

Tags: javascript

I wanted to program a sort of panel from where i can send command to user For a live game that came to mind using jquery, javascript and php.
I take as a reference for every user using SESSION of php.
The initial user will have a

```
         setInterval(function(){ 
     var xml = new xmlHTTPRequest();
    xml.open('GET','http://samepage.php?data= I don't know',false)
    xml.send()
    if(xml.responseText=="color"){
hideloader();
ShowFavoriteColorForm();
    }
        }, 3000);
```

The point is that I can't figure out how to use ajax to do a function that is waiting for something from another page (a string for example) and then perform other operations.
If there were examples or documentation in this regard, thank you very much.

Comment: The page will be open in the same browser?

Comment: if you want to receive messages in real-time from the server while your page is open, then you need to look into websockets